# SOAP client basic auth: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized'

Tags: java, xml, authentication, soap

I'm trying to creat a SOAP client that has to call a server that uses http basic authentication.
I get the following error:

```
    org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
...
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/services/ContractService?wsdl=ContractService.wsdl
```

My app-config.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">  

    <security:http auto-config="true">  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/*"/>  
        <security:http-basic/>  
    </security:http>  

    <security:authentication-manager>
       <security:authentication-provider>
           <security:user-service>
           <security:user name="wsuser1" password="pw123" authorities="wsuser" />
           </security:user-service>
       </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="client" class="hu.bz.ikti.insurance.service.insurer.ContractService"
        factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create"/>

    <bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceClass" value="hu.bz.ikti.insurance.service.insurer.ContractService"/>
        <property name="address" value="http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/services/ContractService?wsdl=ContractService.wsdl"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The http basic auth is configured in the servers web.xml:

```
   <security-constraint>  
    <web-resource-collection>  
      <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>  
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <auth-constraint>  
      <role-name>wsuser</role-name>  
    </auth-constraint>  
  </security-constraint>  
  <login-config>  
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>  
  </login-config>  
  <security-role>  
    <role-name>webservice</role-name>  
  </security-role>
```

In tomcat-users.xml the user is added:

```
<user username="wsuser1" password="pw123" roles="wsuser"/>
```

I can open the wsdl in the browser giving username/password.
What can cause this 401: Unauthorized error in the client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the CXF documentation here:

https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html (see Configuring a Spring Client (Option 2))

The correct way to set the username and password is by using the `username` and `password` properties in your `clientFactory` bean configuration.

So add these inside your `clientFactory` bean:

```
<property name="username" value="yourUsername"/>
<property name="password" value="yourPassword"/>
```

Comment: Without the security: prefix i get an xml parsing error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'user'` I added the prefix based on a web example. Maybe i need a xsi:schemaLocation for user (maybe for authentication, etc) elements.

Comment: Didn't say to touch the security prefix at all. You need to add the properties to your `clientFactory` bean.

Comment: @Syon. This was an extremely useful suggestion. I struggled with this for a day, and then found this answer and voila, it worked like a charm. Thanks!